# Property [group] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, has-many, belongs-to

I have retrieved an instance of a product item at blade, so when I do `dd($product)`, I get this result:

[image]

And the `Product` Model is connected to `GroupProduct` Model like this:

```
public function groupproducts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(GroupProduct::class,'product_id','id');
}
```

So at `group_product` table, the product has a custom `group_id` like this:

[image]

So when I do `dd($product->groupproducts);` I get this result properly:

[image]

Then at the Model `GroupProduct`, I've added these two relationships:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'product_id','id');
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class,'group_id','id');
}
```

Now I need to access the name of the group that comes with the retrieved `product_id`, but when I try this:

```
dd($product->groupproducts->group->name);
```

I get this error:

### **Property [group] does not exist on this collection instance.**

However the relationships seems to be applied and it should be showing the name of group...

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

---

**UPDATE #1:**

Controller:

```
public function addAttribute(Product $product)
{
        return view('admin.products.addAttribute', compact('product'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$product->groupproducts` is a collection(array) of products.
You can do:

```
dd($product->groupproducts->first()->group->name);
```

This will get first element from collection which is instance of `Group` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your relation from your product model to the group products model is a [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). This means, that even if there's only one result, you will be receiving a collection.

You can see in your own screenshot that the return value of `$product->groupproducts` is an instance of a collection with 1 item.

If you only ever want the first, you should change your relation to a [one to one](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

However, if you just want the first in this particular case, you should call for the first on the *query* instance, **not** on the *collection* instance.

So `$product->groupproducts()->first()->group->name`. This way you don't load x amounts, but instead only 1, from your database, which is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **nested relationship**:

1- you can use it in your Model via:

```
public function groupproducts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(GroupProduct::class,'product_id','id')->with('group');;
}
```

2- you can use it in your controller:

```
Products::with('groupproducts.group')->get()
```

[REFRENCE](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading)